# MySQL sum of two COUNT statements

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I know this has a stupid solution but, sorry, I'm little bit confused.

I have two SELECT COUNT statements. Example:

*Statement 1*

```
SELECT COUNT(softwareone) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table WHERE softwareone LIKE '%typeone%'
```

totalcount = 3
_

*Statement 2*

```
SELECT COUNT(softwaretwo) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table WHERE softwaretwo LIKE '%typeone%'
```

totalcout = 1

I want to sum both totals to get totalcount = 4. There is a way to do that?

Note: software type from columns "softwareone" and "softwaretwo" is of the same type (same value).

Thanks to all.

Comment: Is it on purpose that both selects filter on `%typeone%`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to write:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN softwareone LIKE '%typeone%'
                 AND softwaretwo LIKE '%typeone%'
                THEN 2
                ELSE 1
            END
          ) AS "totalcount"
  FROM my_table
 WHERE softwareone LIKE '%typeone%'
    OR softwaretwo LIKE '%typeone%'
;
```

The `CASE ... END` expression will evaluate to `2` when both conditions are met (so that if `softwareone` and `softwaretwo` are both `LIKE '%typeone%'`, then the row counts twice), and `1` when only one of them is. So, the `SUM(CASE ... END)` gives the total number of rows where the one condition is met, plus the total number of rows where the other condition is met.

Comment: +1 The subquery solutions cause MySQL to scan through the records multiple times. This query only causes MySQL to scan through once.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a

```
Select l1.totalcount + l2.totalcount FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(softwareone) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table WHERE softwareone LIKE '%typeone%') as l1,
(SELECT COUNT(softwaretwo) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table WHERE softwaretwo LIKE '%typeone%') as l2
```